# Qt JSON – query from subitems

Tags: c++, json, qt, qt5, jsonparser

I have a problem with querying a sub-item from a sub-item.

**JSON file:**

```
{
    "user": {
        "url": "www",
        "set": {
            "s_a": 1,
            "s_b": 2,
            "s_c": 3,
            "s_d": 4,
            "s_e": 5
        }
    }
}
```

**Qt:**

```
QString value = jsonfile
                .object()
                .value("user")
                .toObject()
                .value("url")
                .toString();
```

**Qutput:**

```
www
```

**Question:** Why doesn't the following work?

```
QString value = jsonfile
                .object()
                .value("user")
                .toObject()
                .value("set")
                .toObject()
                .value("s_a")
                .toString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's because s_a is not a string value but an Int one.

This should work:

```
int value = jsonfile
            .object()
            .value("user")
            .toObject()
            .value("set")
            .toObject()
            .value("s_a")
            .toInt();
```

Comment: I have searched so long on subitem functions that I have not seen the obvious! 

Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Of course this works "only" for s_a, from s_b you get only zero back as value.

Comment: According to the json you showed, it should work with any of `s_*` field simply by replacing the name. What code did you use?

Comment: I had a memory conflict that caused this error from value 2, and returned 0. The code you posted is 100% correct!